# Oracle SQL: return only max value

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query results in 2 rows. I added the last 'and' statement in order to only show the result where the height was the max height but, the report still returns 2 rows?

```
select ds.catnr, pd.part_no, pd.description, ds.packtyp, pd.qty_box, ds.planqty, ds.weight_g, 
round((ds.planqty/pd.qty_box),'1') X, bom.av_part_no, lg.height, lg.length, lg.spine width, lg.part_no, lg.description
from oes_delsegview ds, part_description pd, 
TABLE(leos_flatbom_pkg.GetFlatBOM(pd.part_no)) bom, 
leos_gen_part_picture lg
where ds.ordnr = '0021565475'
and ds.posnr = '00002'
and ds.segnr = '001'
and ds.catnr = pd.catnr
and ds.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp
and ds.packtyp = pd.packtyp
and bom.prodtyp = 'KT'
and bom.av_part_no = lg.part_no
and lg.height = (select max(lg1.height) from leos_gen_part_picture lg1 where lg.part_no = lg1.part_no)
```

Why does the 'height = max(height)' not restrict my result and how can I change the script to only show the row where 'height = max(height)'?

Current result...

[image]

Required result...

[image]
Thanks

Comment: How many rows does it return without the last condition? Also 2? If yes, then the reason why is that you are comparing `height` of a particular row with it's `max(height)` since you are retrieving it for every `part_no` (where clause in inner select statement).

Comment: I can't see any output, so which two lines are you talking about? Also, they are rows not lines. Also, you might have more than one row with same MAX height.

Comment: I get 2 rows when not using the last condition, heights are each row are different, result added to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible to tell for sure without the data but I'd suggest

1) You have not got the same conditions on the max as the rest of the query

2) There are two rows with the same height

Comment: heights are each row are different, result added to question

Comment: got it ... you were correct, I missed one of the condition on the max as the rest of the query. Max condition amended to ...

and lg.height = (select max(lg1.height) from TABLE(leos_flatbom_pkg.GetFlatBOM(pd.part_no)) bom1, leos_gen_part_picture lg1 where bom1.prodtyp = 'KT' and bom1.av_part_no = lg1.part_no)

Comment: Glad you sorted it out and happy I could help